# 0x / web3.js - Overflow when swapping direct

Tags: web3js, 0x

I'm getting quote from 0x on fantomchain w/o takeraddress. I then submit direct swap transaction by 2x'ing gas price and 3x'ing gas.. and i'm getting this strange error:

```
const sellToken = "DAI";
const buyToken  = "WFTM";




/*
 selllAmount = 100 dai
 */


const sellAmount= "100000000000000000000"; 


const swap = {
    "sellToken"         : sellToken, 
    "buyToken"          : buyToken, 
    "sellAmount"        : sellAmount
};

const qs = createQueryString({
    "sellToken" : sellToken,
    "buyToken"  : buyToken,
    "sellAmount": sellAmount,
    "slippagePercentage" : 0.001
});

const API_QUOTE_URL=`https://fantom.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote`;
const quoteUrl = `${API_QUOTE_URL}?${qs}`;

const q1 = {
    "json" : await fetch(quoteUrl);
}

const gas       = parseInt(q1.json.gas)      * 3;
const gasPrice  = parseInt(q1.json.gasPrice) * 2;    

const direct_swap = {
    "from"      : account.address,
    "to"        : q1.json.to,
    "data"      : q1.json.data,
    "value"     : q1.json.value,
    "gasPrice"  : gasPrice,
    "gas"       : gas
};

///////////////////
// this fails
///////////////////


const receipt = await web3.eth.sendTransaction(direct_swap);
```

Error I am getting:

```
/home/django/capn/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:208                                                                        
        throw this.makeError(message, code, params);                                                                                         
        ^                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                             
Error: overflow (fault="overflow", operation="toNumber", value="192638632734728879460997978907331638097635593347", code=NUMERIC_FAULT, versio
n=bignumber/5.5.0)                                                                                                                           
    at Logger.makeError (/home/django/capn/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:199:21)           
    at Logger.throwError (/home/django/capn/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:208:20)                                          
    at throwFault (/home/django/capn/node_modules/@ethersproject/bignumber/lib/bignumber.js:305:19)                                          
    at BigNumber.toNumber (/home/django/capn/node_modules/@ethersproject/bignumber/lib/bignumber.js:153:13)                        
    at /home/django/capn/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/coders/array.js:89:60                                                           
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)                                    
    at Object.unpack (/home/django/capn/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/coders/array.js:85:12)                                           
    at TupleCoder.decode (/home/django/capn/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/coders/tuple.js:39:49)
    at AbiCoder.decode (/home/django/capn/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/abi-coder.js:93:22)                                            
    at ABICoder.decodeParametersWith (/home/django/capn/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js:303:30)                                       
    at ABICoder.decodeParameters (/home/django/capn/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js:284:17)                                           
    at ABICoder.decodeParameter (/home/django/capn/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js:273:17)                                            
    at sendTxCallback (/home/django/capn/node_modules/web3-core-method/lib/index.js:521:50)                                                  
    at /home/django/capn/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:302:20                                                           
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/home/django/capn/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:98:13)                     
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/django/capn/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
```

Where am i going wrong with this?

Note: I am purposefully not using gas/gas price from the quote, but instead adding "buffer" by 3x'ing gas and 2x'ing gasPrice.

Comment: Looks like a conversion issue to me. Can you try to replace parseInt with new BigNumber or a string?

Comment: i tried BigNumber as well - same error

Comment: (new BigNumber(q1.json.gas))..multipliedBy(3) .... then adding to swap params via .toString()- doesn't seem to make a difference (i.e. same error)

Comment: for some reason, this error doesn't occur on Ropsten chain.. but it does on Fantom chain